# Why "while len(x)" is giving Correct Answer and "while x" is giving Time Limit Exceeded?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, tree

Given a binary tree, connect the nodes that are at same level. You'll be given an addition nextRight pointer for the same.

Initially, all the nextRight pointers point to garbage values. Your function should set these pointers to point next right for each node.

```
       10                          10 ------> NULL
      / \                       /      \
     3   5       =>            3 ------> 5 --------> NULL
    / \   \                  /  \         \
   4   1   2                4 --> 1 -----> 2 -------> NULL
```

My Code:

```
def connect(root):
    q = []
    q.append(root)
    while q:
        x = len(q)
        for i in range(x):
            curr_node = q[0]
            if i!=x-1:
                curr_node.nextRight = q[1]
            if curr_node.left:
                q.append(curr_node.left)
            if curr_node.right:
                q.append(curr_node.right)
            q.pop(0)
    '''
    :param root: root of the given tree
    :return: none, just connect accordingly.
    {
        # Node Class:
        class Node:
            def __init__(self,val):
                self.data = val
                self.left = None
                self.right = None
                self.nextRight = None
    }
```

Note that when I use `while q` I'm getting Time Limit Exceeded and when I use `while len(q)`, I'm getting correct answer. Can anyone tell me the reason as to why this is so?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me with both `while q:` and `while len(q):`. You're forgetting to set `nextRight` to `None` when `i == x-1`.  It says that `nextRight` is initialized to garbage.

Comment: If you feel like optimizing this code slightly, use a collections.deque rather than a list.  popping off the first element of a list is slow, but dequeues are optimized for adding and removing from both ends.

Comment: `while q` and `while len(q)` shouldn't have any appreciable difference in execution time.

Comment: Perhaps provide some example input with benchmarking to show the timing difference? "Some (unspecified) website is timing out when I make this change" is not enough information to determine if the fault is with your code or if it's the website.